# StatsModel Logistic Regression

Tags: python, logit, statsmodels

I am running a fairly simple Logistic Regression model y= (1[Positive Savings] ,0]) X = (1[Treated Group],0)
 I got a coefficient of Treated -.64 and OR of .52. 
My question is how to interpret the meaning of the coefficient?

Is y base 1 and X base 0

My thoughts are that the treatment X 0 is .47% less likely to show positive savings?

Is it always 0 being the base in the binary or categorical?

can I get stats model to give 0- 2 or 0-3 as Odds Ratio as well?

Comment: Couple of things here: response $y$ has no base level since it's a random variable that follows the Bernoulli distribution. Concerning regressor $x$, the value which brings this variable at base level is $x=0$, but the domain-specific level (e.g. experiment vs control) that's used as your base level has to do with the software you're using.

Answer (score 2):

In your model:

$$ y \sim Binomial(n, p) $$
$$logit(p) = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x $$

you get: 
$$ log{p \over{1-p}} = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x $$
$$ log{~O_{y|x}} = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x $$
and solving for $\beta_1$ gives you:
$$ \beta_1 = (\beta_0 + \beta_1) - \beta_0  $$
$$ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~\beta_1 = log{~O_{y|x=1}} - log{~O_{y|x=0}}  $$
$$\beta_1 = log{~O_{y|x=1} \over ~O_{y|x=0} } $$
and finally:
$$exp(\beta_1) = {O_{treatment} \over O_{control}} $$

Since your OR is in fact $exp(-.64) = 0.53$, you can convert this to a percentage via $(exp(\beta_1)-1) \times 100 = -47$% and conclude that:

*The average probability of getting positive savings is 47% lower at level "treatment" than level "control".*

If independent variable $x$ were continuous you would say:

*The average probability of getting positive savings gets 47% lower for every unit increase in $x$.*

Comment: Is level control always the lowest binary value?

Comment: No. The base level is whatever you set $x=0$ to be. In your case this is control. I also explained this under your question as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

The OR is exp(-0.64) ~ 0.53.  This is the ratio: odds(Y=1 | X=1) / odds(Y=1 | X=0), where odds(Y=1 | X=x) is P(Y=1 | X=x) / P(Y=0 | X=x).

If X is continuous, then you get the same odds for any one-unit difference in X, e.g. odds(Y=1 | X=2) / odds(Y=1 | X=1) is also ~ 0.53.

If you want the OR for a two-unit difference, just take exp(2 * -0.64).

Comment: Thanks. so my question is X is binary so .53 less likely to have savings than 'non flag group' odds going from x= 0( baseline) to X = 1 which is the target group i was trying to investigate?

Comment: The odds is monotone with the probability.  So the odds ratio (OR) being less than 1 means that the probability that y=1 when x=1 is less than the probability that y=1 when x=0.  If the OR is 1 then the two probabilities are equal.  If the OR is greater than 1, then the probability that y=1 when x=1 is greater than the probability that y=1 when x=0.